# Do React Native Firebase's listeners optimize Auth and FireStore queries or is it recommended to create a custom cache?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

In my React Native app I currently have custom hooks that are called by context providers and deliver the state of the application.

In these custom hooks I make a call to the FireStore or Auth to get the necessary data. I use listeners since I read that we are charged only if the result change.

I'm new to Firebase and React Native so I'm wondering if this way of doing will cost me a lot of unuseful transactions or slow down the app.

Firestore charge for reads when the data is modified. It does not charge for listeners, neither for writes.

Here as some code extract to make my point clearer:

The user provider functional component:

```
// Create the context objects
export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(null)

// Provide the context to the app via the FirebaseContextProvider
const FirebaseContextProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  // Get the state objects and functions using custom hooks
  const user = useAuth()
  // Return the context providers
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
}
```

The related custom hook:

```
function useAuth() {
  // Set an initializing state whilst Firebase connects
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true)
  const [user, setUser] = useState<AuthUser | null>()

  // Handle user state changes
  function onAuthStateChanged(user: AuthUser) {
    if (user) {
      setUser(user)
    } else setUser(null)
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged)
    return subscriber // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, [])

  if (initializing) return null

  return user
}
```

The userData provider, that returns additional data from firestore, use a similar provider and this custom hook:

```
function useUserData() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState<UserData | null>(null)
  const { firebase } = useContext(FirebaseContext)
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firebase.db
      .collection('people')
      .doc(user!.uid)
      .onSnapshot((documentSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot) => {
        setUserData(documentSnapshot.data() as UserData)
      })

    // Stop listening for updates when no longer required
    return () => subscriber()
  }, [])

  return userData
}
```

Is it a good way to code this when you want to optimize your Firebase costs and avoid unnecessary re-renders in React Native ?

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is that you're trying to optimize.

Comment: Avoid too many calls to Firebase. Avoid unnecessary re-renders in React Native. I'm not sure that there is a problem. Actually the problem is more that I don't know if this is a good way to code it. I will try to make it clearer.